# angular 4 assign promise return value to global variable

Tags: angular, promise, undefined

How can I assign return value from promise to outside/global variable?

In my service.ts, I have a promise method that returns a number.

```
getNumber(username: string): Promise<number> {       
    return this.Test.deployed().then((instance) => {
        return instance.getNumber.call(username);
    })
    .then((value) => {    
      return this.itemsService.getSerialized<number>(value);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
  }
```

In home.component.ts, I call `getNumber()` in `ngOnInit` and assign its return value to global variable `isGreaterThanZero`.

```
isGreaterThanZero: boolean = false;

constructor(private service: myService){}

ngOnInit() {    
    ...
    var result = this.service.getNumber(userName);  

    result.then((value) => {
        if (value > 0) {
            this.isGreaterThanZero = true;
        }          
    })
}
```

and in html,

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="isGreaterThanZero"
```

Looks easy at first glance, but can't figure it out on my own. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but you only described what you intend to do. What's the problem with this code? Where do you stuck?

Comment: Well, no, don't do that. You must wait for the promise before using `isGreaterThanZero`

Comment: so how can i wait and properly assign its returned data to `isGreaterThanZero`?

Comment: You are waiting before assigning it. You probably are not waiting before using it. (If you want to use it in the template, you probably need to re-apply it, but I don't know Angular)

Comment: There's nothing wrong about the syntax above. Even the order in which he assigns it is correct. I'd guess that his promise doesn't deliver a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.service.getNumber(userName).then((value) => {
    if (value > 0) {
        this.isGreaterThanZero = true;
    }          
});
```

If this doesn't work make sure that you actually receive a value from your promise. Maybe there is your problem located.

you could verify this by inserting an alert() or console.log().

```
this.service.getNumber(userName).then((value) => {
    alert('value from promise: ', value);
    if (value > 0) {
        this.isGreaterThanZero = true;
    }          
});
```

Comment: That's no different than using a temporary `result` variable to store the promise.

Comment: Sorry mate, you've been too fast. Please read my additional comments before voting me down.

Comment: @Bergi: If you don't know Angular, why do you answer this question?

Comment: I didn't answer the question? And while I don't know Angular in detail, I know enough about JS and promises to conclude that your suggestion will not solve the problem.

Comment: It certainly won't, but it will help to debug the cause of the problem. And I do know a lot about Angular. As I said. The code snipped in the given example is correct. isGreaterThanZero starts with the value of "false" and gets changed to "true" if, and only if, the expected return value is received. Angular would the apply the changed value and rearrange the DOM-Elements.